# PHP If, Else variable not setting correctly

Tags: php

```
<?php
$campaign = $_GET['campaign'];
$straightlink = "https://link1";
$sublink = "https://link2";
if ($campaign = "1234abc"){
 $link = $sublink;}
else { $link = $straightlink;}
?>
```

I'm testing this code with echo`echo $link` and the output is always link2

I need link2 to echo when campaign matches the string
and link1 to appear in any other situation.

Comment: `$campaign = "1234abc"` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quantify with a `true` statement or a `truthy` statement.  You are **setting something equal to**  `===` vs `==` vs `=`

`=`      Sets a variable "equal to"
`==`    Truthy -- 1 and '1' are treated as "equals"
`===`  Truth --  1 and '1' and NOT the same  -- Will return false

Also it is worth noting you need an `elseif` when you have a second query -- Which I created a fake one so you can view the syntax.  `elseif( $link == 'abcdefghi')`

```
<?php
    $campaign = $_GET['campaign'];
    $straightlink = "https://link1";
    $sublink = "https://link2";
    
    if ($campaign === "1234abc"){
        $link = $sublink;
    }
    elseif( $link == 'abcdefghi') { 
        // Do something 
    }else{
        $link = $straightlink
    }
```